# Can I marry a non-virgin women by myself being a virgin muslim

Tags: nikah

**Can I marry a non virgin girl who had premarital relationship with her ex-boyfriend?**

I recently got to know this and my wedding is going to be held. I'm confused and not able to tell this to anyone as well. I can not tell my parents as they are happy about this marriage and are already making arrangements for it. I'm worried about what would happen if I called it off as it will be a bad name on me. But also I can't ensure whether I'd happy with this marriage or not.

Comment: have a look here. https://islamqa.info/en/104492 But keep in mind there is difference in she herself saying she did zina and someone else saying she did so and so... If someone else says someone is zani, there is very strict rules to prove it. Otherwise the one who said so is punished as zani by qazi.

Comment: also this https://islamqa.info/en/137912

Comment: Yes you can but first she has to repent for losing her virginity before marriage. Then you can marry her. You don't have to worry about telling anyone.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fp4KWyiiB8

Comment: @curiosity on what basis are you saying "You don't have to worry about telling anyone"?

Answer (score -2):

Why are you confused, to be a virgin doesn't mean you are a good person.
A Virgin is not batter than some who's not. 
If you love her and wants to marry her and know that she's a good person and knows that she's not a virgin. Then why are you even asking this question 
You are making yourself frustrated thinking about something that's not even serious

Ask yourself this question "Do You Love Her?"

Sometimes Allah swt give us what we want but over think it and push it aside.

A marriage doesn't have anything to do with being a Virgin or not it's about two people loving each other and wanting to spend the rest of their life together.